# How-to make Hibernate Validator stop validation on the first field violation?

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

I have a bean where I define multiple validation annotations for each field e.g.

```
@NotEmpty
@Pattern(regexp="(\\-?\\d)+")
@Min(value=1)
String myField;
```

I have encountered <strike>two</strike> one problem that I cannot resolve in any easy way.

1. <strike>Validation order of the specified annotations for each field is random i.e. do not happen in the order the annotations are defined. I believe @GroupSequence will not help since it only defines group validation sequence, not annotation sequence.</strike>
   As @Tom correctly commented, violations are reported as Set which means there is no 1:1 mapping between execution order of annotations and reported violations.
2. I want to invalidate only one rule for each field i.e. if it does not match pattern do not try to check if the value is >= 1. Currently if is set myField to "abc" it will report both @Pattern and @Min violations. Setting failFast property of a validator to true does not help because I'm using the same validator instance to validate all the fields in my bean, and it will stop validating other fields as soon as the first violation for the whole bean is encountered.

Edit. I tried to implement custom composite constraint with @ReportAsSingleViolation. The problem is that it will report the same message for all violations involved in composition. This is not what I need.

Suggestions, please?

Comment: Are you sure that validation order is random? As far as I remember, the validator returns a `Set` of `ConstraintViolation`. This set does not have a particular order. So there is no connection between the validation order and the order of reported violations.

Comment: @Tom
OK, maybe they are executed in the defined order. But you are right, unless Set interfece is backed by one of the ordered set implementations, there cannot be 1:1 mapping between execution order and order of reported violations. Which means that what I'm actually looking for is answer to my second question.

Comment: You could check that by using a debugger and see which implementation of `Set` is used there. It might be a `LinkedHashSet`, but I assume it is just a normal `HashSet`. Well, for the second part: I currently see only one dirty solutions: write your own validator for each field. But I hope someone else (who has more experience with Hibernate Validator) has a much better idea :).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be possible to create the behavior you want to achieve using a combination of [validation groups](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/#validator-usingvalidator-validationgroups) and a fully defined [validation group sequence](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-groupsequence)

Quoting from [JSR-349 (aka. BeanValidation 1.1) spec, paragraph 4.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidatorContext.html)

> Processing a group is defined in *Section 4.6* ; if one of the groups processed in the sequence generates one or more constraint violations, the groups following in the sequence **must not be processed.** This ensures that a set of constraint is evaluated only if another set of constraint is valid.
>   <sub>highlighting by me</sub>

This should be relatively easy, going by the [Group Sequence Example](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidatorContext.ConstraintViolationBuilder.html)

```
@GroupSequence({YourClass.class, Second.class, Third.class})
public class YourClass {
    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp="(\\-?\\d)+", groups=Second.class)
    @Min(value=1, groups=Third.class)
    String myField;
}
```

with `Second` and `Third` defined as simple marker-interfaces should do the trick. Be aware that this does not validate all fields until the first constraint violation, but just until the first overall violation.

This means some of your fields may **become** invalid after fixing other fields' violations.

If all else fails you can still reimplement the behavioral components, your Validation Provider.
You should be able to provide your own implementation of the [`ConstraintValidatorContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidatorContext.html) by using a validation.xml

Be aware you'd **have** to break the contract of [`ConstraintValidatorContext.ConstraintViolationBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidatorContext.ConstraintViolationBuilder.html):

> To create the ConstraintViolation, one must call either one of the
>   addConstraintViolation() methods available in one of the interfaces of
>   the fluent API.
>
> If another method is called **after addConstraintViolation()** on
>   ConstraintViolationBuilder or any of its associated objects an
>   `IllegalStateException` is raised.

Answer (score 1):

You could [compose your constraints](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#constraintsdefinitionimplementation-constraintcomposition). But with that you would get only one error for any of the constraints specified, not sure if thats acceptable in your use case.

Comment: Then @davidgale perhaps you might mention that in your question. I believe that you need to write your own constraint/validator implementation.

Answer (score 0):

So far you have to use the `@GroupSequence` solution described in the other answer. However, the Hibernate team is looking for a solution with the coming features of JDK, and even working with OpenJDK developers: [BVAL-248](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/BVAL/issues/BVAL-248?filter=allopenissues)

Answer (score 0):

see guide: [failFast mode](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-fail-fast)

```
Validator validator = Validation.byProvider( HibernateValidator.class )
        .configure()
        .failFast( true ) // stop at first 
        .buildValidatorFactory()
        .getValidator();
```