# How to define vonstraint validation order across multiple fields/properties

Tags: jersey, bean-validation, hibernate-validator, spring-validator

How to get validation error messages according to the order of field declaration
ie. in sequence.

Ex:
 
    `@EmptyCheck(message = "{contactName.empty}")
    private String contactName;
    @EmptyCheck(message = "{personal.empty}")
    private String personalNo;`

For this in first request am getting contactName cant be null and followed by second message 
But for second request am getting personalNo cant be null and followed by second message.

How can we make it to execute in the order of declaration. Please help me to resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no order defined between fields in a class. Validation order is undefined unless you start using group sequences. See also [How-to make Hibernate Validator stop validation on the first field violation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27018180/how-to-make-hibernate-validator-stop-validation-on-the-first-field-violation)